# How to avoid reference compress in ACM latex?

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I use the [ACM LaTeX template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). When I cite multiple continuous references I get

> [1-5]

However, I kindly don't want to compress the reference number

My expect result is

> [1,2,3,4,5]

Any way to achieve this goal?

Here is my demo code, basically, I don't modify the original LaTeX template

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08emT\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
hello word \cite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{acmart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `acmart` has both a `biblatex` and a BibTeX style. Which one are you using? Would it be possible to add a short example document with a few citations to your question so we have something to start from? (An MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) Note that if you want to submit to the ACM you should probably not try to work around the style imposed by their templates. Chances are they won't like it, it also increases the potential for errors and incompatibilities if you modify their template.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the explanations. I use ACM latex template before, and it is in style [1,2,3,4,5].  But the newest version in the style [1-5]. I think you're right. I should follow their new style. Thanks.

Comment: A short look at the documentation suggests though that it is possible to change certain things, so they don't seem to be opposed to some changes, but you should probably still check back with the exact style guide for the journal you want to publish in. It would be great if we could have an answer for this question, so it would still be appreciated if you could prepare an MWE.

Comment: @moewe, I add more detail about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are reasons for the default settings of the `acmart` document class. Unless you have explicitly been asked by the publisher to change the behaviour of their class I would not take action.

Anyway, the documentation suggests that limited interventions from the author side might be OK. The class loads `natbib` by default, so you can disable the compression with `\setcitestyle{nocompress}`.

Using `sample-base.bib` from the `samples` subdirectory of the `.zip` file at https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template or https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/tree/master/samples we can get

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\setcitestyle{nocompress}

\begin{document}
\cite{Abril07,Cohen07,Obama08,Goossens:1999:LWC:553897,Kirschmer:2010:AEI:1958016.1958018}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]